# How to open ssh session and execute commands from a Perl script?

Tags: perl, ssh

I have a Perl script running on a Windows machine. I need this script to open a ssh session to a remote Unix machine, and to be able to execute certain commands on that Unix machine and to be able to get the output returned from these commands.

These commands are generated during the run-time of the script, and there are many of them executed at different times.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Approach 1: Use CYGWIN: http://perlwin32ssh.blogspot.com/2007/07/test_4418.html

Approach 2: Use `Net::SSH::W32Perl` module.

This is one thread discussing how to install it: http://code.activestate.com/lists/perl-win32-users/29180/ (It seems to require downloading custom version of the module)

This thread should help with the problems arising from dependencies on math libraries needed for ssh calculations: http://www.issociate.de/board/post/494356/I%27m_trying_to_install_%27Net::SSH::Perl%27_on_a_Windows_Box..html

Caveat emptor: I never installed this, the above is just result of some analysis of google results.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

system("ssh foo 'ls -l'");
```

Or go through the hassle of using ptmx(4) on the local side and `ssh -t` for remote.

Comment: which won't work on Windwos (as required in questions) as it doesnt have an SSH command.

Comment: Well, that would require an ssh client on your windows machine. Do you have one?