# How to accomplish ssh implementation on windows using script

Tags: perl, ssh

I'm running a Perl script on windows machine that needs to use SSH for logging into
network elements.
How can I accomplish this? Any idea?
Since windows doesn't support SSH how can i implement this?

Regards
Madhu

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to open ssh session and execute commands from a Perl script?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4533741/how-to-open-ssh-session-and-execute-commands-from-a-perl-script)

Answer (score 0):

you install [putty](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/) and use that.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14269885/putty-scripting-to-log-onto-host) might help you, or [using port forwarding](http://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/0.63/htmldoc/Chapter3.html#using-port-forwarding) might be more helpful, you haven't given enough information to know exactly what you want.